# sql change all data in one column in table partially , like change all email address from @gmail to @yahoo

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with name and email Ids of all the students.
Email ids end with @yahoo.com or rediff.com etc, Is there any way to change them all to say @gmail.com ? 
I am using sql server.

Comment: Update your title for consistency. Your title says gmail to yahoo, but your question is yahoo to gmail.

Comment: You should try to figure out how to solve the question yourself before asking here. If you've already tried to solve it somehow, please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE t
SET email = 
  REPLACE(
    emailIn
    , SUBSTRING(
        emailIn
        , CHARINDEX('@', emailIn)
        , LEN(emailIn) - CHARINDEX(emailIn, '@')
    )
    , '@gmail.com'
  )

COMMIT TRAN
```

Use the transaction to make sure you've got the email addresses you want. It's MUCH easier to ROLLBACK than it is to restore a backup.

Comment: What is emailIn in your query?

Comment: @ZaheenHaris Sorry, emailIn is just a placeholder for the email address you want to change.

Comment: @ZaheenHaris mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem!      ~ Sincerely, from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `replace()`:

```
select replace(email, '@yahoo.com', '@email.com')
```

You can also put this into an `update`, if you want to change the data in the table.

This is safe for emails, because `@` appears only once in the email address.

```
update t
    set email = replace(email, '@yahoo.com', '@email.com')
    where email like '%@yahoo.com';
```

Comment: I appreciate your fast response. But all email addresses are not same. some are yahoo, rediff etc. I want them all changed to gmail.com

Comment: @ZaheenHaris . . . You should ask a different question.  This one is clearly about emails that end in "yahoo.com".  Changing a question after it has been answered is unfriendly, because such changes can invalidate answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, run the following query:

```
      UPDATE your_table_name 
      SET your_column_name = REPLACE(your_column_name,
      '@yahoo.com','@gmail.com ');
```

Likewise you can also do with @rediff.com by replacing it with @yahoo.com and so on.

Comment: You should add the main points from that link to your answer rather than posting a link. The page you're referring to could change or go away rendering your answer obsolete

Comment: You can still edit you comment and add these details. No need to wait for next time :-)